# Android: Get a MJPEG stream from camera

Tags: android, android-camera, mjpeg

I want to get a MJPEG stream from my Android camera and send it via RTP to a server. What is the best way to get a MJPEG stream from camera?
I am developing for Android 2.3

Comment: Have you seen this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815103/android-streaming-the-camera-as-mjpeg

Comment: Yes but it deals with the RTP sending part. I want a solution to the Capturing part.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.  Thanks!